# What programmable devices can be used to teach artificial intelligence?

Tags: programming-languages, education

Could you give examples of affordable programmable devices that could be used in university classes to teach students about A.I. and demonstrate it?

The devices are expected to do some form of self-learning, pattern recognition, or any other features of A.I., and to be programmable or customizable.

Comment: We're working on it at MClass Games/Fundamental Combinatronics.  (Still in the early stages, but our goal is to integrate an AI scripting interface, not just for for College level, but down through middle school, and to make it available to educational institutions for free.)

Answer (score 4):

[LEGO Mindstorms](https://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms) is widely used to demonstrate AI in schools and universities [[1](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b515/dcdb633e2de2101a1eabfc53ecf84f5fcd39.pdf), [2](http://www.legoengineering.com/)]. With LEGO as basis, you are very flexible. You can build what you want very easily. The AI programs can be written in different languages from very easy graphical once to Lisp and C++. The newest version has an SD Card drive, USB interface and a powerful ARM processor. You can use four motors and four sensors directly. There exists touch, sound, sonar, gyro, infrared and color sensors. There is also a big community which provides you with a lot of ideas, hardware and programs [[3](https://www.hackster.io/mindstorms)].

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try android Phones with Tensorflow [TensorFlow Android Camera Demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android)

You can build a simple image or text classification neural network to demonstrate AI.

Answer (score 0):

To start you could use one of the devices mentioned before, and after to make some more powerful and complicated experiments (and also a little bit more expansive) you could move to [Jetson TK1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00L7AWOEC) which let you run heavier Neural Network (like CNN).